# Type dependent implicits

Tags: scala, shapeless

Two implicits are needed in the function, but I can't have them in the
same parameter list, because I get `dependent method type`. So I
considered currying once more, but that gives me a syntax error.
What's the correct way to do this?

```
def add[A](newAnnotations: Seq[A])
    (implicit maybeAdd: MaybeAdd[L, Seq[A]])
    (implicit mod: Modifier[maybeAdd.Out, Seq[A], Seq[A]]):
    Slab[Content, maybeAdd.Out] = {
  val l = maybeAdd(annotations, Seq[A]())
  l.updateWith(_ ++ newAnnotations)
}
```

Comment: You cannot have implicits in different parameter list. They MUST be placed in the end and together.

Comment: You should investigate the `Aux` pattern in shapeless: it arose to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited `MaybeAdd` to have an `Aux` type, as suggested by @milessabin.

```
def add[A, Out0](newAnnotations: Seq[A])(implicit maybeAdd: MaybeAdd.Aux[L, Seq[A], Out0], mod: Modifier[Out0, Seq[A], Seq[A]]): Slab[Content, mod.Out] = {
  val l = maybeAdd(annotations, Seq[A]())
  new Slab(content, mod(l, _ ++ newAnnotations))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the syntax error is likely to be:

```
illegal dependent method type: 
parameter appears in the type of another parameter in the same section or an earlier one
```

Meaning one cannot use the dependent type in the same section, only in the next parameters block or as a return type only.

See "[A short introduction to the `Aux` pattern](http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html)" byLuigi.

```
 type Aux[A0, B0] = Foo[A0] { type B = B0  }
```

> basically Aux is just a way to extract the result of a type level computation

As noted in "[Why is the Aux technique required for type-level computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548518/6309)"

> the `Aux` type aliases are entirely a syntactic convenience.
>
> The Aux version has a couple of advantages over writing out the type refinements in this way: it's less noisy, and it doesn't require us to remember the name of the type member.
> These are purely ergonomic issues, though—the `Aux` aliases make our code a little easier to read and write, but they don't change what we can or can't do with the code in any meaningful way.