# Why is the Aux technique required for type-level computations?

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, since I'm pretty new to Shapeless and I'm learning, but when is the Aux technique actually **required**? I see that it is used to expose a `type` statement by raising it up into the signature of another "companion" `type` definition.

```
trait F[A] { type R; def value: R }
object F { type Aux[A,RR] = F[A] { type R = RR } }
```

but isn't this nearly equivalent to just putting R in the type signature of F ?

```
trait F[A,R] { def value: R }
implicit def fint = new F[Int,Long] { val value = 1L }
implicit def ffloat = new F[Float,Double] { val value = 2.0D }
def f[T,R](t:T)(implicit f: F[T,R]): R = f.value
f(100)    // res4: Long = 1L
f(100.0f) // res5: Double = 2.0
```

I see that path-dependent type would bring benefits *if* one could use them in argument lists, but we know we can't do

```
def g[T](t:T)(implicit f: F[T], r: Blah[f.R]) ...
```

thus, we are still forced to put an additional type parameter in the signature of `g`. By using the `Aux` technique, we are *also* required to spend additional time writing the companion `object`. From a usage standpoint, it would look to a naive user like me that there is no benefit in using path-dependent types at all.

There is only one case I can think of, that is, for a given type-level computation more than one type-level result is returned, and you may want to use only one of them.

I guess it all boils down to me overlooking something in my simple example.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are two separate questions here:

1. Why does Shapeless use type members instead of type parameters in some cases in some type classes?
2. Why does Shapeless include `Aux` type aliases in the companion objects of these type classes?

I'll start with the second question because the answer is more straightforward: the `Aux` type aliases are entirely a syntactic convenience. You don't ever *have* to use them. For example, suppose we want to write a method that will only compile when called with two hlists that have the same length:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Length

def sameLength[A <: HList, B <: HList, N <: Nat](a: A, b: B)(implicit
  al: Length.Aux[A, N],
  bl: Length.Aux[B, N]
) = ()
```

The `Length` type class has one type parameter (for the `HList` type) and one type member (for the `Nat`). The `Length.Aux` syntax makes it relatively easy to refer to the `Nat` type member in the implicit parameter list, but it's just a convenience—the following is exactly equivalent:

```
def sameLength[A <: HList, B <: HList, N <: Nat](a: A, b: B)(implicit
  al: Length[A] { type Out = N },
  bl: Length[B] { type Out = N }
) = ()
```

The `Aux` version has a couple of advantages over writing out the type refinements in this way: it's less noisy, and it doesn't require us to remember the name of the type member. These are purely ergonomic issues, though—the `Aux` aliases make our code a little easier to read and write, but they don't change what we can or can't do with the code in any meaningful way.

The answer to the first question is a little more complex. In many cases, including my `sameLength`, there's no advantage to `Out` being a type member instead of a type parameter. Because Scala [doesn't allow multiple implicit parameter sections](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/), we need `N` to be a type parameter for our method if we want to verify that the two `Length` instances have the same `Out` type. At that point, the `Out` on `Length` might as well be a type parameter (at least from our perspective as the authors of `sameLength`).

In other cases, though, we can take advantage of the fact that Shapeless sometimes (I'll talk about specifically *where* in a moment) uses type members instead of type parameters. For example, suppose we want to write a method that will return a function that will convert a specified case class type into an `HList`:

```
def converter[A](implicit gen: Generic[A]): A => gen.Repr = a => gen.to(a)
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)

val fooToHList = converter[Foo]
```

And we'll get a nice `Foo => Int :: String :: HNil`. If `Generic`'s `Repr` were a type parameter instead of a type member, we'd have to write something like this instead:

```
// Doesn't compile
def converter[A, R](implicit gen: Generic[A, R]): A => R = a => gen.to(a)
```

Scala doesn't support partial application of type parameters, so every time we call this (hypothetical) method we'd have to specify both type parameters since we want to specify `A`:

```
val fooToHList = converter[Foo, Int :: String :: HNil]
```

This makes it basically worthless, since the whole point was to let the generic machinery figure out the representation.

In general, whenever a type is uniquely determined by a type class's other parameters, Shapeless will make it a type member instead of a type parameter. Every case class has a single generic representation, so `Generic` has one type parameter (for the case class type) and one type member (for the representation type); every `HList` has a single length, so `Length` has one type parameter and one type member, etc.

Making uniquely-determined types type members instead of type parameters means that if we want to use them only as path-dependent types (as in the first `converter` above), we can, but if we want to use them as if they were type parameters, we can always either write out the type refinement (or the syntactically nicer `Aux` version). If Shapeless made these types type parameters from the beginning, it wouldn't be possible to go in the opposite direction.

As a side note, this relationship between a type class's type "parameters" (I'm using quotation marks since they may not be *parameters* in the literal Scala sense) is called a ["functional dependency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class#Functional_dependencies) in languages like Haskell, but you shouldn't feel like you need to understand anything about functional dependencies in Haskell to get what's going on in Shapeless.