# Could not find implicit value while using Context Bound

Tags: scala, implicit, context-bound

I'm using the following code written in Scala 2.11.8:

```
  sealed trait Acceptable[T]

  object Acceptable {
    implicit object Int extends Acceptable[Int]

    implicit object String extends Acceptable[String]
  }

  case class Enc[T](f: T => Any)

  implicit def test[I, T](implicit f: I => T, a: Acceptable[T]): Enc[I] =
    Enc[I](f)

  val e = implicitly[Enc[Int]]
```

It successfully compiles.

As you can see `a: Acceptable[T]` parameter should be easily converted to [context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds):

```
implicit def test[I, T: Acceptable](implicit f: I => T): Enc[I] =
    Enc[I](f)
```

But after that change compilation is starting to fail with error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter e: app.Enc[Int]

Why does this happen?

**UPDATE:**

I tried `-Xlog-implicits` compiler option and compilation log gives me:

```
[info] /path/to/ScalaTest/src/main/scala/app/Main.scala:60: test is not a valid implicit value for app.Enc[Int] because:
[info] hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
[info]  both object Int in object Acceptable of type app.Acceptable.Int.type
[info]  and object String in object Acceptable of type app.Acceptable.String.type
[info]  match expected type app.Acceptable[T]
[info]   val e = implicitly[Enc[Int]]
[info]                     ^
[info] /path/to/ScalaTest/src/main/scala/app/Main.scala:60: app.test is not a valid implicit value for app.Enc[Int] because:
[info] hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
[info]  both object Int in object Acceptable of type app.Acceptable.Int.type
[info]  and object String in object Acceptable of type app.Acceptable.String.type
[info]  match expected type app.Acceptable[T]
[info]   val e = implicitly[Enc[Int]]
[info]                     ^
[error] /path/to/ScalaTest/src/main/scala/app/Main.scala:60: could not find implicit value for parameter e: app.Enc[Int]
[error]   val e = implicitly[Enc[Int]]
```

Ok, I understand this output. But why does it work in case of implicit parameter?

Comment: `-Xlog-implicits` is your friend in this case. It will show why compiler disregarded your available instance.

Comment: @Haspemulator I added compiler output with this option. But I still do not understand the difference between context bound and implicit parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a reference for this, but in my experience implicits corresponding to a context bound are searched for *before* any other "explicit" implicit parameters; your method

```
implicit def test[I, T: Acceptable](implicit f: I => T): Enc[I] =
  Enc[I](f)
```

is equivalent to

```
implicit def test2[I, T](implicit a: Acceptable[T], f: I => T): Enc[I] =
  Enc[I](f)
```

which as you can easily check doesn't work either. Why? from the output it looks like the compiler *first* tries to look for an implicit `Acceptable[T]` and it *fails* at this point, due to ambiguity; at this point it stops searching for anything else. What is confusing is the *error message*, which IMHO should be something like "failed searching for Acceptable[T]: ambiguous implicits" or something like it.

Why the other method works? because of the *order* of the implicit parameters. The compiler will search first for `f: I => T` and this will most likely bind `T` to `Int`, *and then* we do have a unique `Acceptable[Int]` implicit in scope. In general

- I wouldn't mix context bounds and implicit parameters
- The order of implicit parameters is important, and they should be arranged so that finding one determines the next uniquely

As far as I know all this is not spec'ed and depends on the current implementation; the above is based mostly in my experience debugging implicits errors.

Comment: Multiple implicit parameter lists could be possible, but it currently isn't - so far, the solution is the [Aux Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541271/what-does-the-aux-pattern-accomplish-in-scala#38543999).

Comment: Eduardo, thanks. You are totally right. I did not thought about order of implicits.